# Velocity and mass and particles

Tags: velocity, mass-energy, higgs

If mass increases as velocity increases how can I associate this with the fact that some particles such as neutrinos which barely have no mass, go faster when they have less mass or less interaction with the Higgs field. Or does it mean that a neutrino, if I try to accelerate it will increase in mass which could mean that if the neutrino increase in mass it's velocity increase too...? So if a photon which has no mass increase its mass it's velocity will increase(
obviously no It is just for the purpose of explanation). So if the photon's velocity is higher than the neutrino's does it mean it has more mass...which is the opposite of what the interaction with the Higgs field tell us. So the question remains: how can I associate the 2 facts together.

Comment: How would you accelerate a neutrino?

Comment: That is why I thought that quantum mechanically It did not make sense to say that mass increase as velocity increase for particles and it only work for classical mechanics as Anna explained to me.

Comment: Relativistic mass can be a confusing and misleading concept. I recommend that you avoid it. It's considered deprecated in modern treatments of relativity. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133376/why-is-there-a-controversy-on-whether-mass-increases-with-speed and the links on that page for details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elementary particles are quantum mechanical entities and are governed by the [postulates of quantum mechanics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html) and the theories developed withing it,and by the mechanics of [special relativity](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html).

You are using classical mechanics intuition for a framework, elementary particles, where it does not work. Classical mechanics emergence from the underlying frameworks of the microworld  can be demonstrated mathematically in a [complex  manner.](https://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html)

Let us try to see the misunderstanding:

> If mass increases as velocity increases

The mass that is increasing as velocity increases, is the inertial mass, i.e. the mass that is need to balance classical mechanics postulates, F=ma, which is only useful in trying to describe the kinematics of spaceships traveling close to the velocity of light. It is called the [relativistic mass.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity#Relativistic_mass)

Relativistic mass is not used,  in particle physics, where the mass describing the particles is the length of the special relativity  four vector for each particle. That is invariant to Lorentz transformations and *characterizes uniquely* particles and complex systems.

[image: invarmass]

> how can I associate this with the fact that some particles such as neutrinos which barely have no mass, go faster when they have less mass

This is wrong. The mass of the neutrinos, the rest mass,does not change with motion. At rest, it is the same as the relativistic mass. Their relativistic mass is irrelevant for the particle interactions that just need the four vectors to balance energy and momentum.

> or less interaction with the Higgs field

This is also a misconception coming from popularization of particle physics.

*The Higgs mechanism* is not *an interaction,* it gives a unique mass to elementary particles at [electroweak symmetry breaking time](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/timlin.html#c1%22) in the creation of matter in our universe, once.  It is part of [the model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) on how particles acquire their unique mass.

One has to study physics at graduate level to be able to understand the mathematical models used.  The popularization tries to give an equivalence in a classical model on how particles move in a space where a Higgs field exists, but *it is not what is happening in the microworld of particles and the interactions controlling their motion.*

Hope this helps.

Comment: the mass given by the Higgs mechanism is the one that is in the model of particle physics corresponding to the rest mass (relativistic or inertial mass...) what is the difference between these masses and the four vectors given by quantum mechanics, thank you for the explanation. I also thought the particle rest mass had an influence on the velocity so how does an elementary particles gain it's velocity if it is not because of their "inertial" mass?

Comment: the rest mass is  *different* than the relativistic mass.Look at the link. the rest mass is not velocity dependent but constant. The four vectors give the invariant/rest mass. It does not change with velocity. The elementary particles gain their energy and momentum by interactions, described by Feynman diagrams. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram  They exchange energy and momentum according to special relativity rules. That is how they can increase or decrease their momentum, and therefore since their mass is fixed,their velocities

Comment: Ok, but what do you mean by the rest mass is the same as relativistic mass , if it is the same then why can't we use the relativistic mass for particles..."The mass of the neutrinos, the rest mass,does not change with motion. At rest, it is the same as the relativistic mass. Their relativistic mass is irrelevant for the particle interactions "

Comment: The statement is about particles at rest, velocity 0. Then the relativistic and invariant mass formulae are the same, and only then. Once the particle has velocity they are different. A particle at rest is not interacting or moving . Once motion and interactions enter the two formulae are different

Comment: If the mass was given only once at a time long ago, what about the particles which are created today, for example via pair production? If two photons produce a pair of particles, they get their mass today, not 14 billion years ago, don't they?

Comment: @СимонТыран  what holds for the value of the masses holds also for the value of the spectra for specific atoms The values are fixed by the constants defining the potentials in the shrodinger equation, no matter how may atoms are formed  anew ( an electron captured by a proton forms a hydrogen atom with the same spectra as all hydrogen atoms) The mass of fundamental particles is the same case, dependent on more complicated mathematics, when pair created they have the generic mass .